# Dúvida para uma atividade

Tags: javascript

3) Faça um código em Javascript que mude o valor do conteúdo do elemento de texto para “Pedro Brigatto”.

Tenho que alterar o valor desse value nesse input:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mudar aqui">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual é a duvida que tens?

Answer (score 5):

O código poderia ser este:

```
document.getElementById("myText").value = "Pedro Brigatto";
```

```js
document.getElementById("myText").value = "Pedro Brigatto";
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mudar aqui">
```

Comment: #perfeito! Aperfeiçoei mais um pouco abaixo! Mas a sua resposta foi bem mais direta! :)

Comment: valeu cara obrigado

Comment: @user95806 Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não te restar mais nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como aceita/correta ao clicar no "✅" aqui do lado, o que também marca a sua pergunta como respondida/solucionada. Se preferir a outra resposta, então marque ela (só é possível marcar uma como aceita). Se por outro lado, ainda não estiver satisfeito com nenhuma das respostas, deixe um comentário e vamos esclarecer.

Answer (score 4):

Para você selecionar um elemento do HTML no JavaScript, sete o seu campo com um ID, caso use uma vez, como foi feito no seu código:

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mudar aqui">
```

Nesse caso, o seu ID é "myText".

No JavaScript, você precisa pegar esse dado e setar ele, assim como o @DvD fez na resposta anterior, mas quem faz isso para você é o:

```
document.getElementById("AQUI VAI O SEU ID");
```

Quando você coloca o **.value** após esse código, você esta pegando o value do seu campo input. Você pode pegar outros parâmetros, como vou dar alguns exemplos abaixo:

#### Mude o parâmetro classe:

```
document.getElementById("myText").class = "Pedro Brigatto";
```

#### Mude o parâmetro id:

```
document.getElementById("myText").id = "Pedro Brigatto";
```

Espero ter contribuído com o seu conhecimento! :)

Comment: Deve ser `className` e não `class`. `+1` por explicares o código!

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio! No meu funcionou assim. Mas vou me precaver da próxima vez. Fico agradecido pelo feedback!

Comment: obrigado cara valeu